# Using Stackdriver debug for non-Java JVM languages

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

The Stackdriver debug interface complains when you have a non-java file in your source (such as a Groovy file).

The way a debugger normally works is that it matches a filename and line number to the  sourcefile and linenumber attributes included in the class file, so I'm not sure why support for non-java source files was disabled.

Did anyone have any luck "tricking" the interface into accepting non-java files (e.g. by renaming them), or have any information about whether Google is planning to add support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limitation is hardcoded in the Stackdriver Debugger Java agent. See 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java/blob/master/src/agent/internals/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/java/ClassPathLookup.java#L186

The reason for the limitation is that the agent was built for java. It understands Java conditions and expressions (and doesn't understand other languages expressions).   The agent can be modified to handle other JVM languages with relatively few changes.  However, the file:lines much match the info in the class files and the expressions parser modified to match the target lanuage.

Comment: Unfortunate to see such an arbitrary restriction, using Java conditions and expressions to debug Scale, Groovy, Clojure, etc. code would be perfectly sane, and every half decent JVM language spits out classes with proper line number attributes.

Comment: This would provide a starting point for seeing if you can trick the platform (you'd "only" need to rename the class attributes and files in a branch of your repo). I can see why Google wouldn't want blanket support for any language, but hopefully they'll test if the popular JVM languages could work properly one day.

Comment: Incidently https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java/commit/aacb0d0348d6f6202e20908f5cac020fb30b6d2b seems to have created dead code at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java/blob/master/src/agent/internals/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/cdbg/debuglets/java/ClassPathLookup.java#L191